# mlr3 - Editing `task$data()`

Tags: r, mlr3

Is there a way to edit `task$data()` or replace it with a new `data.frame()` with exactly the same colnames?

I've tried the following `task_train$data() <- newDF` and `task_train$data <- newDF`. They both result in `Error in task_train$data() <- di : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment` and `Error in task_train$data <- newDF: cannot change value of locked binding for 'data'`, respectively.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Please provide the context.

Comment: Just exploring `mlr3` interface. I guess there is not practical application of this --- It is just better if all the editing on the dataset is done before creating a task.

Comment: Once you create the task all further data transformations, augmentations etc. should be performed using pipelines. This is especially handy when performing resampling/tuning since it avoids data leakage.

Comment: @missuse Could you post this comment as a full answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you create the task all further data transformations, augmentations etc. should be performed using [pipelines](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/). This is especially handy when performing resampling/tuning since it avoids data leakage.

Based on the comment by [@pat-s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4185785/pat-s) this is not only my opinion but the opinion of the core mlr team. And this is the reason why direct editing of the task data (in ways you show in the question) fails.

Answer (score 0):

One use case is for swapping knockoff data in place of the real data for measuring conditional effects of features as in the {cpi} package. This would allow other key parts of the `task` to remain (e.g., weights, coordinates) and only modify the data itself.

`mlr_pipeops_mutate` gets us what we want: [help file here](https://mlr3pipelines.mlr-org.com/reference/mlr_pipeops_mutate.html)

```
library("mlr3")
library("mlr3pipelines")

constant = 1
pom = mlr3pipelines::po("mutate")
pom$param_set$values$mutation = list(
  Sepal.Length_plus_constant = ~ Sepal.Length + constant,
  Sepal.Area = ~ Sepal.Width * Sepal.Length,
  Petal.Area = ~ Petal.Width * Petal.Length,
  Sepal.Area_plus_Petal.Area = ~ Sepal.Area + Petal.Area,
  Sepal.Width = Sepal.Width / 2.54 # modify column in place
)
```